# JAXB/xjc: Generate classes from child elements and load them based on class types

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

I have a configuration file in XML, which looks something like:

```
<configuration>
     <database>
          <host></host>
          <port></port>
     </database>
     <queue>
           <host></host>
           <port></port>
           <type></type>
      </queue>
</configuration>
```

I would like to use JAXB/xjc to generate Java classes for this configuration, however I would like to generate these classes and unmarshal these one level into the tree. Rather than receiving a Configuration.java, I would like a Database.java and Queue.java (in order that these can be separately injected into a Guice managed application). I don't (currently) see any way of doing this, however may be searching for the wrong things.

---

After some experimentation, I have found a solution to generate these classes and be able to populate and return these based on class:

First, I added a bindings.xjb file which will generate the contained classes (Database and Queue in this example)

```
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

However, JAXB can't unmarshall using the Database or Queue class, only the Configuration class (this is where I may have missed something). I can do

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
Configuration conf = (Configuration) um.unmarhal(xmlFile);
```

but not

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Database.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
Database db = (Database) um.unmarhal(xmlFile);
```

However, because I can get the database object by calling getDatabase() on an instance of the Configuration object, this can also be made generic using reflection (making this code cache results in the appropriate places is another exercise):

```
    T item = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Configuration conf = (Configuration) um.unmarshal(xmlFile);
        Method[] allMethods = Configuration.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : allMethods)
        {
            if (method.getReturnType().equals(clazz))
            {
                item = (T) method.invoke(conf);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (JAXBException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new ConfigException("Failure detected while loading configuration", e);
    }
    return item;
```

I'm not sure this is the best solution (I only started working with JAXB yesterday), but seems to fulfill my goal.

Comment: Since you know you are unmarshalling an instance of `Configuration` you don't need to be as dynamic as you're being with reflection.  You know what properties and their types are already.

Comment: In addition, if I pass Database.class or Queue.class in this to this method, I can have a copy of those provided by this method and am not limited to injecting a full copy of the application configuration everywhere I want to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am answering this question with my solution to the problem as discussed in the question. This meets my requirements:

---

After some experimentation, I have found a solution to generate these classes and be able to populate and return these based on class:

First, I added a bindings.xjb file which will generate the contained classes (Database and Queue in this example)

```
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings localScoping="toplevel"/>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

However, JAXB can't unmarshall using the Database or Queue class, only the Configuration class (this is where I may have missed something). I can do

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
Configuration conf = (Configuration) um.unmarhal(xmlFile);
```

but not

```
JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Database.class);
Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
Database db = (Database) um.unmarhal(xmlFile);
```

However, because I can get the database object by calling getDatabase() on an instance of the Configuration object, this can also be made generic using reflection (making this code cache results in the appropriate places is another exercise):

```
    T item = null;
    try {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Configuration.class);
        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Configuration conf = (Configuration) um.unmarshal(xmlFile);
        Method[] allMethods = Configuration.class.getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method : allMethods)
        {
            if (method.getReturnType().equals(clazz))
            {
                item = (T) method.invoke(conf);
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (JAXBException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        throw new ConfigException("Failure detected while loading configuration", e);
    }
    return item;
```

This allows me to get an unmarshalled Database by passing Database.class without needing to hardcode methods for ever configuration parameter. These can then be injected where needed without needing to inject the entire unmarshalled XML file.

Answer (score 0):

That particular XML would correspond to a `Configuration` class that had properties of type `Database` and `Queue`.  Isn't this what you are looking for?

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Configuration {

    private Database database;
    private Queue queue;

}
```

Comment: Not quite. I am looking for to additionally generate separate classes Database and Queue (edit: can't put a line break in a comment). I've managed to come up with a solution that generates these classes through JAXB and then a reflection based solution in order to be able to return just the filled in classes after unmarshalling to Configuration, and will be updating the question for others to find/possibly show a better way of doing things.

Comment: Do you mean generate top level classes instead of nested ones?  If so check out:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/07/jaxb-xjc-and-nested-classes.html

Comment: @CharlesA - If you just want to unmarshal the ‘Database` and `Queue` objects the following will help:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

Answer (score 0):

Step1: Create 3 classes configuration.java, database.java, queue.java

configuration.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "configuration")
public class configuration{

  @XmlElement
  private database db;
  @XmlElement
  private queue q;
  ...
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class database{
  @XmlElement
  private String host;
  @XmlElement
  private String port;
....
}

-------------------------

    InputStream xmlStream = new FileInputStream(config.xml);
    JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(configuration.class, database.class,queue.class);
    Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
                    configuration config= (configuration) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(xmlStream);

    config.getDatabase().getHost(); //returns the host
    config.getDatabase().getPort(); //returns the port

------------------------------------
```